# MySQL values have a space in front?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a MySQL table called `furniture` setup like this:

```
|  id  |    name     |  identifier  |
===================================
|  1   | "? Block"   |  "?-block"   |
|  2   |"1-Up Block" | "1-up-block" |
|  3   |"Alarm clock"|"alarm-clock" |
```

When I run this PHP code, the string returned is `1-up-block` but with a space at the beginning of the string; the MySQL interface does not show this space. It is screwing up my programming.

```
$id = 2;
$fier = '';
$prep_stmt = 'SELECT identifier FROM furniture WHERE id = ?';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);
if ($stmt) {
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($identifier);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $fier = $identifier;
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
echo $fier;
```

Why would this space appear, and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Why don't you use `trim` function

Comment: `SELECT trim(identifier) as identifier FROM furniture WHERE id = ?` perhaps.

Comment: Its either in the db or your code adds it

Comment: The problem is that I must run `SELECT name FROM furniture WHERE identifier = "1-up-block"` sometimes, but I have to put a space in front of it.

Comment: @Dagon It seems like it's in the DB, but the MySQL interface doesn't show it

Comment: Might be worth cleaning the db.  And checking how the data gets in

Comment: @Dagon I tried doing this `UPDATE furniture SET identifier = LTRIM(identifier)` but the problem persists.

Comment: Perhaps its not a real space character

Comment: Almost certainly the space is in the database - try dumping the database (`mysqldump`) and look at the resulting file for the extraneous spaces. You don't say what MySQL interface you are using that isn't showing the spaces, but I've used a few in the past that don't always show the data correctly.

Comment: A check of something similar to: `ORD(identifier) <= 32` will return the rows where the first character in the `identifier` column is a `space` or `ctrl` character. if you select `HEX(identifier)` then you can see the actual value of the character in the column.

Answer (score -1):

You could do a `LIKE` query for this. But Might be worth cleaning the DB and if you can adjust the script that insert this entry into the DB

```
SELECT name FROM furniture WHERE identifier LIKE "1-up-block"
```